# D3.js line chart not displaying on screen

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

D3.js line chart not displaying in window

Hi I'm fairly new to javascript and going by a few examples I mocked up this implementation of a d3.js linechart. For some reason it is not drawing the graph on the window, instead giving me a blank screen.

```
var chartdata = [{
    time: "1-May-12",
    emissionrate: "58.13"
}, {
    time: "30-Apr-12",
    emissionrate: "53.98"
}, {
    time: "27-Apr-12",
    emissionrate: "67.00"
}, {
    time: "26-Apr-12",
    emissionrate: "89.70"
}, {
    time: "25-Apr-12",
    emissionrate: "99.00"
}];
//regular single compound chart
function chart (width,height,data) {
    var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
    },vis = d3.select('#chartvis');

  var w = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  var h = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    data.forEach(function (d){
    d.time=parseDate(d.time);
    d.emissionrate=+d.emissionrate;
  });

  var xmin = d3.min(data,function(d){
    return d.time;
  });
  console.log(xmin);
  var xmax = d3.max(data,function(d){
    return d.time;
  });

  var ymax = d3.max(data,function(d){
    return d.emissionrate;
  });
  console.log(ymax);

  var xLine =  d3.scaleTime().domain([xmin, xmax]).range([0, w]);
  var yLine = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, ymax]).range([h, 0]);

  var lineFunc =  d3.line()
                                    .x(function(d) {
                                    return xLine(d.time);
                    })
                    .y(function (d) {
                    return yLine(d.emissionrate);
                    });

    vis.append('g')
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +     ")");

     vis.append('g')
            .attr("id", "xAxis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xLine));

     vis.append('g')
            .attr("id", "yAxis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + w + ", 0)")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yLine));

     vis.append("path")
            .data(data)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-width","1.5")
            .attr("d", lineFunc);


}

chart(400,500,chartdata);
```

I expect any kind of graphical output, but instead am getting a blank screen. Inspecting in the dev tools is not giving me any errors either.
I have attached the JsFiddle here as well

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbogd94/2/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at the browser console, are there any errors that might help you?

Comment: nothing in the console unfortunately aside from the couple console.log values i had it output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 major issues. First, it seems there is a bug on jsfiddle when using d3v5. I decide to use plain js and load d3v5 using script tags. After that I start seeing the elements inside the `<svg>` when using the browser tools. I had to adjust the size of the `<svg>` element to see the axis.
The second major issue is the `data` function is for the [Enter-Update-Exit pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234). In your case you should use the datum method.

Here is the updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/75uh2La0/

Comment: Thanks so much man, never would have known about the jsfiddle d3 v5 bug. I resolved my spacing issues too. You rock